# Android SDK: получить id из properties

Tags: android-sdk, android

Я только только начал изучать `SDK` да и c `Java` толком не знаком,и у меня такая проблема.  Повесил на форму пару картинок прописал им `id` в `Properties` типа `"@+id/i00" "@+id/i01"` и так далее, в общем теперь я этот id хочу использовать в качестве индексов для обработки 2-мерного массива, но не могу его достать. В обработчик `OnClick` приходит (`View v`) использую `v.getId()` но он мне возвращает набор цифр,какой то внутренний `id` походу. И как же мне из кода получить именно тот `Id` который я сам указывал,и перевести его в строку?

Answer (score 1):

```
context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId());
```

ну или если прям в Activity, то просто:

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId());
```

Answer (score -1):

`if(v.getId()==R.id.i00 {}`